# Django Settings Apps Model

Tags: django, model

I want to know what is the meaning of "Config" in installed_apps in django like this

```py
    'polls.apps.pollsConfig'
```

Is it okay to put only the name of the apps example 'sample_apps'?

Comment: Here the **`pollsConfig`** is the **class name**, which is located in **`/polls/apps.py`** file

Answer (score 0):

In the subfolder polls you have a file apps.py with a class named PollsConfig

**polls/apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'polls'
    verbose_name = 'PollsApp'
```

This file is autogenerated by django when you create a new class but you can modify it to add some proprieties.